# C++: Shared_Ptr segfaults on virtual method call, but not dereference

Tags: c++, polymorphism, shared-ptr, virtual-functions

Currently my code looks like this:

```
class A
{
    public:
    //A(A&&);
    A& operator=(const A&);
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<B>> myVec;

    int accessMyFunc() {
        return myVec[0]->myFunc();
    }
}

class B
{
    public:
    virtual ~B();
    virtual  int myFunc() const = 0;
}

class C : public B
{
    public:
    virtual int myFunc() const override {/* do stuff*/}
}

A makeanA()
{
    A temp;
    temp.myVec.emplace_back(new C)
    return temp;
}
```

When I run this main

```
int main()
{
    A theA;
    theA = makeanA();
    theA.accessMyFunc();
}
```

I get a segfault from the -> within accessMyFunc.  However, `*myVec[0]` does not segfault, and I have checked within the assignment constructor for A that the shared_ptrs are being copied properly.  Why would this segfault be occurring not on dereference, but on the method call?  Especially when the assignment constructor verifies that the shared_ptr of the lhs and the rhs both point to the same spot?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: how A(A&&) is implemented? Also - as long as method does not touch anything 'around' this it might not segfault, as no 'bad' memory is touched.

Comment: That function actually isn't called at all, I put a cout statement inside it and it is never called.  However it still causes a segfault when `A theA(makeanA()) ` is used in place of the first two lines of main.  Will add to post.

Comment: Why are you returning "A" in method "makeanA()"? Shouldn't you be returning temp?

Comment: typo, sorry about that

Comment: We need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This code doesn't compile on it's own.

Comment: ok, I am going to try to reproduce this and will close this question

Comment: I didn't get any segmentation fault when I attempted to recreate this.

Comment: yeah, I'm attempting to recreate it outside of the initial code and can't get the segfault, my bad

Answer (score 0):

So it ended up that my error was dealing with a dynamic/shared library.  I opened the library within a function other than my main, so when the function returned, its attempts to find the virtual table resulted in a segfault